# Is it possible to save a set of breakpoints?

Tags: eclipse

I have a set of breakpoints which I used for debugging one issue. When I want to debug something else, these breakpoints are annoying, so I need to disable/delete them. However, I feel that I might want to be able to recreate the first set of breakpoints later.

**Is it possible to save all currently active breakpoints so that you can switch between different sets of breakpoints with just one operation?**

If I have 30 breakpoints, it would be very tedious to recreate/reenable them all manually.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In Eclipse (debug perspective -> breakpoints) select all the breakpoints, right click, export breakpoints!

Comment: Argh... I cannot believe I didn't notice this. Was expecting it to be an option in the header bar where the "remove breakpoint" and "add exception breakpoint" buttons etc are. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You can use breakpoint working sets - see [eclipse help](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/breakpoints/ref-workingsets_viewaction.htm).

Comment: This seems to be the better solution than the currently accepted one as you can really switch in a second.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find the Breakpoints tab, open it on: `Window > Show View > Breakpoints`.

Then, as said before: `Ctrl+A to select all breakpoints > right click > Export Breakpoints...`.