# Possible to share breakpoints I made in some project?

Tags: android, eclipse, intellij-idea, breakpoints

Is there a way to share breakpoints I create in a certain project so that my colleague can continue the same path?

Can this be shared between IntelliJ IDEA and Eclipse user?

If not, then how to share it between two IDEA users?

PS. it's Android project in question.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11340959/is-it-possible-to-save-a-set-of-breakpoints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In eclipse you can export all your breakpoints to a *.bkpt file and import the same in any other workspace.
Go to debug perspective/breakpoint view. Right click on the breakpoint view. You would see options Export Break Points and Import Break Points.

More details: http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fwizards%2Fref-export_breakpoints.htm